# Correlation between count sparse data?

Tags: correlation, count-data, feature-engineering

Having a matrix size 1000x500. Each row vector is a count of occurrences of events, the vector can be sparse, but what I am interested in is the similarity between row vectors. Let's say that they are counts of disease types sampled in each city, then, for large cities, I will have larger numbers but there might be a linear correlation with other smaller cities that "behave" the same.

```
v1 = [0,0,30,2,0,0,0,231,0,0,1,0....]
v2 = [1,1,0, 0,0,0 0,100 , 0 ,0 ...]
```

I want to calculate the pairwise correlation, i.e the output should be a matrix of correlation coeff in the size of 1000x1000

I would like to calculate the correlation between each row vector. At the moment I'm using Pearson correlation but I don't think it is right and also I get lots of fake correlations when the cities are very small (~less than 30 total events and most of the vector is 0 ).

The end goal is to group similar cities and decrease my categorical cardinality.

Comment: Alternatives to the Pearson correlation do exist. One such is Szekely's *distance correlation* which expresses pairwise dependence based on Euclidean distances. It captures nonlinearity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation Another option is an information theoretic metric of pairwise similarity which doesn't rely on the moments of a distribution. Brandmaier's *permutation distribution clustering* approach is a good example of this. https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i05

Comment: For clarification, when you say `reduce categorical cardinality`, are you talking about making categories of the cities or categories of diseases?

Comment: @abstrusiosity combine cities that 'behave" the same into a grouped city. i.e reduce feature "city" cardinality.

Comment: @MikeHunter tried using Szekely distance correlation and it seems to bring very noisy and unreliable results on my data..

Comment: Scatterplots are always the first place to start when trying to understand pairwise dependence. Pick a few at random among the noisiest results. Also, there are other dependence metrics such as Spearman rank correlation, the Reshef's MIC, and here ... Clark, M., A Comparison of Correlation Measures, https://m-clark.github.io/docs/CorrelationComparison.pdf